# A complement set with coprime numbers

Tags: prime-factorization

I can't understand the result of the following set:

$$
\{\overline{x∈ℚ\hspace{3pt}|\hspace{3pt}x = \frac{z}{y}\hspace{3pt}with\hspace{3pt}x,y,z∈ℤ,\hspace{3pt}y > 1\hspace{3pt}and\hspace{3pt}|z|,y\hspace{3pt}are\hspace{3pt}coprime}\} =\hspace{3pt} ?
$$

The most difficult part for me to visualize is the coprime condition. For example, are the numbers 5, 6, and 35, belong to this set, because 6 and 35 are coprime and $\frac{35}{6}=5$?

Then how can I represent the complement of this set?

Comment: Are you sure that the requirement was not that $|z|$ and $y$ should be coprime?

Comment: I double-checked. The requirement I specified is correct. At least, that's how it reads on my problem sheet.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen It turns out there was indeed a mistake. You're right, |z| and y should be coprime.